# understanding VBA loops

Tags: excel, vba, loops, integer

I am trying to understand what the following VBA loop is doing:

```
Sub iterate_dev()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 10
[paste1] = [copy1].Value
[paste2] = [copy2].Value

Next i

End Sub
```

I did a step through test on the excel spreadsheet the macro is contained in but I only see numbers changing and have no idea what it is copying and pasting and from what worksheets.

Comment: Not sure why there's a loop. It does the same two actions 10 times.

Comment: Could you explain this please? I have experience with VBA but not loops. I guess im confused because the command is paste and then copy instead of copy and paste. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Also how do I know what cells the action is taking place in? Its a huge spreadsheet

Comment: Those are named ranges: Formulas > Name Manager to see what cell(s) they correspond to.

Comment: [paste1] , [copy1] are not *commands* but locations on the sheet

Comment: To print their location in the immediate window. Try this: `Debug.Print [paste1].Address(0, 0, xlA1, True); vbLf; [copy1].Address(0, 0, xlA1, True)`